# elegant template overloading solution?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

In c++11 I have functions

```
double f(double x1);
double f(double x1, double x2);
double f(double x1, double x2, double x3);
double h(double x);
```

I also have functions

```
double g(std::vector<double> y, double x1);
double g(std::vector<double> y, double x1, double x2);
double g(std::vector<double> y, double x1, double x2, double x3);
```

The implementation of g is something like

```
double g(std::vector<double> y, double x1, double x2, double x3)
{
  double ans = 0.0;
  for(g : y)
  {
    ans = h(g) * f(x1, x2, x3);
  }

  return ans;
}
```

Is there an elegant (templated) way of doing this instead of writing g 3 times with overloaded arguments?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html

Comment: Do you really need to restrict `x1` through `x3` to being `double`s?

Comment: The syntax in the definition of `g` is broken,

Comment: @Dlotan for shame! Back to the 17th century?

Comment: @David: The `(...)` signify the difference to the other overloads of `g`, I believe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template<typename... Ts>
double g(std::vector<double> v, Ts&&...ts ) {
  double ret = 1;
  for(auto x:v){
    ret *= h(x)*f(ts...);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

if you want to restrict the `ts` to be `double`s beyond calling `f`, it needs more work.  Otherwise, the above is enough.

(Note the resriction work gets prettier in C++1y with concepts lite: in C++11 I vote to skip the restriction of `Ts` to `double`s, and just rely on `f` only taking `double`s.)

Comment: You should show him how you would implement `f` with variadic arguments too.